# Cannot access string variable assigned in Using() statement c# wp8

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am trying to access a string outside the using statement whose value is assigned inside a using statement as shown below.

I get an error "Use of unassigned local variable 'savedUrl'".

```
customItem.name = ld.Name;
customItem.Location = new GeoCoordinate(ld.Latitude, ld.Longitude, 0);
string savedUrl;
using (IsolatedStorageFile iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    if (iso.FileExists(string.Format("{0}.jpeg", ld.Title)))
    {
        savedUrl = string.Format("{0}.jpeg", ld.Title);
    }
}
addSignPosts();
addLabel(ARHelper.AngleToVector(customItem.Bearing, WCSRadius), customItem.name, savedUrl);
```

As you can see, I declared the string 'savedUrl' outside the using statement so that it will have a scope outside the using statement. But it seems that I cannot access it when it is being assigned inside the using statement.

I tried changing it to a global variable. But it isnt working and it is a bad practice too.

So what I am supposed to do ? Am I missing something here ?

Or is there any workaround for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well yes - if `iso.FileExists(string.Format("{0}.jpeg", ld.Title))` returns false then you won't be assigning a value to `savedUrl`. What value do you want `savedUrl` to have in that case? This has nothing to do with the `using` statement - it's *only* about the `if` statement.

For example, if you want the value to be `null` if the file doesn't exist, you could reverse the logic and assign it the "candidate" value first, setting it to null if the file doesn't exist:

```
string savedUrl = string.Format("{0}.jpeg", ld.Title);
using (IsolatedStorageFile iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    if (!iso.FileExists(savedUrl))
    {
        savedUrl = null;
    }
}
```

Or perhaps use the conditional operator:

```
string savedUrl;
using (IsolatedStorageFile iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    string candidateUrl = string.Format("{0}.jpeg", ld.Title);
    savedUrl = iso.FileExists(candidateUrl) ? candidateUrl : null;
}
```

Note how in both of these snippets, I've changed the code to only call `string.Format` in one place - that makes it easier to change the code consistently later.

Comment: Oh yeah, I got it. I will assign a backup value to the string in case if the `if` statement gives false.

THANKYOU.

Comment: @VenkatapathiRajuM: Right. See my edits for a couple of options for this.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared the variable but have not assigned any value to it there. And the one assignment is in an `if` statement, means it is conditional and there is a possibility that it may not get assigned. So, it's a legitimate error by the compiler.
Try:

```
string savedUrl = "";
```

AND

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(savedUrl)
    addLabel(ARHelper.AngleToVector(customItem.Bearing, WCSRadius), customItem.name, savedUrl);
else
    // Do something here, as the variable is empty.
```

Comment: But I don't want to call the addLabel method from inside the using statement.

What you said is right. I will assign a backup value to `savedUrl` if the `if` statement throws a false.

THANKYOU.

Comment: The code I have added is not to be used in the `using` statement. Just replace the `addLabel` method call's line by the `if-else` code given above.

Comment: Why use an empty string and then `IsNullOrEmpty`? `null` feels like a simpler approach here - it's a more distinctly "no useful value here" value than an empty string, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving it an initial empty string value first, to avoid the error:

```
string savedUrl = "";
```